# Is it possible to use mouseenter and mouseleave event in chart js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, pie-chart

Right now I'm using `onHover` into each pie to add some scale/zoom, but I want to use `mouseenter and mouseleave`. So on `mouseenter` on each pie it will add some scale/zoom, and on `mouseleave`, I want it back to its original state.

either `mouseenter-mouseleave` or `mouseover-mouseout` is fine.

here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/NWNZNyQ

Thanks guys!

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartPie').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 20],
            backgroundColor: [
                'red',
                'blue',
                'green'
            ],
          datalabels: {
            color: '#000'
          }
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
          display: false            
        },
      layout: {
        padding: 5
      },
        onHover: function (evt, elements) {
          let segment;
          if (elements && elements.length) {
            segment = elements[0];
            this.chart.update();
            selectedIndex = segment["_index"];
            segment._model.outerRadius += 5;
          } else {
            if (segment) {
              segment._model.outerRadius -= 5;
            }
            segment = null;
          }
      }
    }
});
```

```css
    .chart-pie {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
<div class="container p-4">
      <div class="chart-pie position-relative">
      <canvas id="chartPie"></canvas>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already designed to return to the original size on mouseout, but you have a subtle bug.

You need to define the `segment` variable *outside* the chart.  With a saved reference to the segment, the `mouseout` event will fire and the `onHover` handler will return the pie to its original size.

Please see the attached example below:

```js
let segment;
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartPie').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 20],
      backgroundColor: [
        'red',
        'blue',
        'green'
      ],
      datalabels: {
        color: '#000'
      }
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    layout: {
      padding: 5
    },
    onHover: function(evt, elements) {
      if (elements && elements.length) {
        segment = elements[0];
        this.chart.update();
        selectedIndex = segment["_index"];
        segment._model.outerRadius += 5;
      } else {
        if (segment) {
          segment._model.outerRadius -= 5;
        }
        segment = null;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart-pie {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
<div class="container p-4">
  <div class="chart-pie position-relative">
    <canvas id="chartPie"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a box shadow when you hover on each pie and remove it on mouseleave?

Comment: Yes, but that's a separate question!  Happy to help in a separate post.  If my answer helped, please accept it :)

Comment: Hi ty, here is the separate Q about it. Thx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64202480/is-it-possible-to-make-a-box-shadow-when-you-hover-on-each-pie-in-chart-js

Comment: @ty. I'm trying to reuse your example in the latest Chart.js version without success. Could you give me a little help?