# Is it possible to make a box shadow when you hover on each pie in chart js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, pie-chart

Right now I'm using `onHover` into each pie to add some scale/zoom, but i want to add some `boxShadow` when you hover it on each pie and remove it when you mouseleave/mouseout on it.

below is the `snippet` of the code.

**UPDATE(s):**

- its working now: chartjs plugin style have been added and snippet
  have been updated.thx

Thanks guys!

```js
let segment;
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartPie').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 20],
            backgroundColor: [
                'red',
                'blue',
                'green'
            ],
          datalabels: {
            color: '#000'
          },
          hoverInnerGlowWidth: 20,
          hoverInnerGlowColor: 'rgba(146,151,164,.5)',          
          hoverOuterGlowWidth: 20,
          hoverOuterGlowColor: 'rgba(127,133,151,1)'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
          display: false            
        },
      layout: {
        padding: 15
      },
        onHover: function (evt, elements) {          
          if (elements && elements.length) {
            segment = elements[0];
            this.chart.update();
            selectedIndex = segment["_index"];
            segment._model.outerRadius += 5;
          } else {
            if (segment) {
              segment._model.outerRadius -= 5;
            }
            segment = null;
          }
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.chart-pie {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-style@0.5.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-style.min.js"></script>
<div class="container p-4">
      <div class="chart-pie position-relative">
      <canvas id="chartPie"></canvas>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: seems like the *chartjs style plugin* has exactly what you want - hoverShadow*

Comment: _chartjs plugin style_ have been added and _snippet_ have been updated.thx

Comment: so, it looks like it's working ..